# Blocking issue in using both threads and Parallel::ForkManager in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, parallel-processing

I have a script that does these two jobs : 
A. Connect to databases and retrieve data from it.
B. Process retrieved data.

And so I create two threads for each of them.
I also utilize Parallel::ForkManager to spawn child processes and do job A so that I can connect to multiple databases at a time.

The problem I have been trying to solve is when I add a blocking call at ForkManager->wait_all_children. Job A is not able to run its callback on finish.

The callback function though will run if I remove my second job (B) from the @threads array.
So I think I have a misunderstanding in using threads, but I thought that 
these two threads are not supposed to be blocking each other. If it is not, what may be the issue here that is causing my child processes to be blocked from finishing its job ?

On the design note, I cannot do job B each time job A is done because job B is very expensive and it may run for quite some time. And therefore it will be blocking me from getting all of job A to be done. So, I would rather have a separate thread that does a "bulk" processing for all of the retrieved data periodically.

Here is my sample code that reproduce the problem I have :

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $isRunningJobThread :shared;    

my @jobs = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
my @threads = (
    threads->create(\&jobThread),
    threads->create(\&compileCompletedJobThread)
);

$_->join for @threads;

print "All done\n";

sub jobThread{
    my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
    $pm->run_on_finish(sub {
        print "Job done\n";
    });

    $isRunningJobThread = 1;
    foreach my $job (@jobs) {
        $pm->start and next;
        print "Do job for : $job\n";
        $pm->finish;
    }

    $pm->wait_all_children;
}

sub compileCompletedJobThread{
    while($isRunningJobThread) {
        sleep 10;

        print "Compiling completed jobs\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use threads and P::FM at the same time? I would only use one or the other.

Comment: Always `fork` before creating any objects. Especially before creating threads! Your children aren't existing. Using `POSIX::_exit` instead of `$pm->finish` can force them to exit, but that can bite you in the ass.

Comment: It seems that pFM isn't operating as usual when in a thread. (What exactly would it even mean to fork a process from within a thread?) From [Process-scope Changes in perlthrtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Process-scope-Changes): "_Thinking of mixing `fork()` and threads? Please lie down and wait until the feeling passes._" I'd say, choose either of the methods (don't forget queues if using threads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, woah. Slow down there. You're doing `threads` and `fork` in the same code. That's a really horrible idea. They're somewhat implementation dependent - you can be *pretty* sure they'll work, but both at the same time is asking for a world of pain. (Concurrency issues, race conditions, etc.).

In this particular case - you need to understand that what `fork()` does is take a complete copy of your process - in exactly the same state - and has a *single* difference - the return code of `fork()`. That means that the threads etc. will be cloned by the `fork()` too. `Parallel::ForkManager` is hiding some of that from you, by limiting the parallelism scope, but that's what's going on behind the scenes.

I'd urge you to step back and make a rewrite - what you appear to be doing would be MUCH better suited to using some worker threads and a `Thread::Queue`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

#parallelism limit
my $num_threads = 5;

#input and output queues
my $work_q = Thread::Queue -> new();
my $result_q = Thread::Queue -> new;

#jobs as before
my @jobs = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');

#worker - reads from queue one item at a time. 
#exits if the queue is 'undef' which happens if it has been `end`ed. 
sub worker {
   while ( my $item = $work_q -> dequeue ) { 
      print threads -> self -> tid.": processing work item $item\n";
      #pretend we did some work, queue the result. 
      $result_q -> enqueue ( threads -> self -> tid . ": finished $item" );
   }
}

#spawn threads
threads -> create (\&worker) for 1..$num_threads;
#queue jobs
$work_q -> enqueue ( @jobs ); 
#close queue, so threads will exit when they hit the end of the queue. 
#dequeue will return 'undef' rather than blocking. 
$work_q -> end;  

#join all the threads. 
$_->join for threads -> list;
#all threads are finished, so we close the result queue. 
#again - so dequeue is undef when empty, rather than just blocking. 
$result_q -> end; 

while ( my $result = $result_q -> dequeue ) { 
    print "Got result of $result\n";
}

print "All done\n";
```

Since you indicate that you're looking to run the 'result_q' in parallel too, then you can do the same thing with the 'result handler' as another thread, with much the same result.

This gets *slightly* ticklish, in that you do need to know your 'exit' condition based on open/closed queues. But something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

#parallelism limit
my $num_threads = 5;

#input and output queues
my $work_q   = Thread::Queue->new;
my $result_q = Thread::Queue->new;

#jobs as before
my @jobs = ( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' );

#worker - reads from queue one item at a time.
#exits if the queue is 'undef' which happens if it has been `end`ed.
sub worker {
   while ( my $item = $work_q->dequeue ) {
      print threads->self->tid . ": processing work item $item\n";

      #pretend we did some work, queue the result.
      $result_q->enqueue( threads->self->tid . ": finished $item" );
   }
}

#a thread to process the results in parallel
sub collator {
   while ( my $result = $result_q->dequeue ) {
      print "Got result of $result\n";
   }
}

#spawn threads
my @workers = map { threads->create( \&worker ) } 1 .. $num_threads;
my $collator = threads -> create ( \&collator );

#queue jobs
$work_q->enqueue(@jobs);

#close queue, so threads will exit when they hit the end of the queue.
#dequeue will return 'undef' rather than blocking.
$work_q->end;

#join all the threads.
$_->join for @workers;

#all threads are finished, so we close the result queue.
#again - so dequeue is undef when empty, rather than just blocking.
$result_q->end;

#reap 'collator' once it's finished.
$collator->join;


print "All done\n";
```

It's pretty much the same as above, but spawns a list of 'workers' - because then you can `end` the `$work_q`, wait for the "workers" to exit (and `join`) - and then you know there'll be no more results entering the `$result_q` and can then `end` that. (And wait for the `collator` to exit).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I can see how your code works, though I have a different end goal.. My end goal is to have result_q to run in parallel with work_q. But the implementation above will block result_q from running until all of work_q is completed. This is the reason why I have "2-level" parallel jobs. The first level is to separate work and result queue, and the second one is to run work_q in parallel.

Comment: You can quite easily coalesce the `result_q` collator in _another_ thread. You just have to modify slightly your tracking of the 'join'. I'll edit in an example.